# hibernate string cannot convert to enum

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

I define hibernate entity like below

```
public class demo {
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  public DemoEnum demoEnum;   
}
public DemoEnum {
    Active("A");
    public String code ;
    DemoEnum(String code) { this.code = code;}   
}
```

then I use criteria to search record. when go to Hibernate `org.hibernate.type.EnumType , public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index)` method.

```
 String enumString = ( ( Enum<?> ) value ).name();
```

this line of code always throw exception that `"String cannot convert to Enum"` ) 
why Hibernate use this way to do the conversion, in fact there are lots of way to convert it. 
I use `hiberate 3.6.10` 
Do I use wrong way to declare the field in hibernate?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Format the code properly and also where is the code that shows you are using to search for some sata?

Comment: Which other way of converting an enum to a String and getting a unique result would work for any enum type?